# Access Point - Port forwarding problems

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I've got Asus RT-N12E. Currently it is working in AP mode (so Firewall and NAT are disabled) with WPA-Auto-Personal and AES+TKIP. I want to set up a game server. When I try to check with canyouseeme.org whether the ports are open, I receive "Connection timed out" error. I have no firewall active on my computer.

Comment: Your question title says "problem", yet your question doesn't say what you've tried and what problems you've ran into. As a side note: log on to your ISP modem/router -> give your game server a reserved IP -> go to the router firewall/service/port forward pages and create a port forward rule for your game server port and direct it to the reserved IP of your game server.

Comment: I can't access my ISP modem. I tried to connect to its IP, but my browser just throws "Couldn't connect".

Comment: You need to access it because it's the device that forwards external requests to your LAN (game server).